# How does Exie's name fit into the gambling theme of Waver and Chance?

Tags: river-city-girls

I know that Waver sounds like Waiver, as in to relinquish ownership of something, like in a bet, and she comes from ''Sugoro Quest Dice No Senshi Tachi'', a game about dice, and other gambling.

And that relates to games of Chance, but how does Exie relate to those themes?